# Strange result of mutiplication with JAVA code

Tags: java

I wrote a simple Java code.

```
while (x != 0) {
      ret = ret * 10 + x % 10;
      x /= 10;
}
```

If I give x = 1534236469, It's expected to return 9646324351. However, it actually returns 1056389758 instead.
While debugging, I found that when it is doing 964632435*10, the result is 1056389758 rather than 9646324350.

Can anybody help me to understand this?

Comment: Is `ret` an `int`?  The largest possible value of `int` is 2147483647.  If you want larger numbers, use `long` or `BigInteger`.

Comment: try long to declare ret , as normal int cannot store such big values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `ret` to a `long`

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int x = 1534236469;
    long ret = 0;
    while (x != 0) {
        ret = ret * 10 + x % 10;
        x /= 10;
    }
    System.out.println(ret);
}
```

output is (as you expected and if I make `ret` an `int` I get your specified output)

```
9646324351
```

From [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html),

**`int`**: By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of (2^31)-1. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the int data type to represent an unsigned 32-bit integer, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of (2^32)-1. Use the Integer class to use int data type as an unsigned integer. See the section The Number Classes for more information. Static methods like compareUnsigned, divideUnsigned etc have been added to the Integer class to support the arithmetic operations for unsigned integers.